# How to get SelectedIndex from another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selectedindex

I'm trying to add and employee and their job all at once.  I have an ID table I'm trying to insert both records into.  I have a FIND button that opens up a combobox on another form that is populated with Jobs.  Once the selection is made it populates the txtJobName textbox on the first form.  That populates with the Job Name like it should but I can not pull the SelectedIndex to insert into the TJobEmployees table.

```
'Variables
Dim strSelect As String
Dim strInsert As String
Dim strFirstName As String = ""
Dim strLastName As String = ""
Dim strJob As String = frmSelectJobName.strSelectedJob
Dim intJobID As Integer
Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim cmdInsert As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim intNextHighestRecordID As Integer
Dim intRowsAffected As Integer
Dim result As DialogResult


strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text
strLastName = txtLastName.Text
strJob = txtJobName.Text
intJobID = CInt(frmSelectJobName.lstJobs.SelectedValue)

If Validation() = True Then

  If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

    ' No, warn the user ...
    MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine &
                                "The application will now close.",
                                Me.Text + " Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    ' and close the form/application
    Me.Close()

  End If

  ' always ask before adding!!!!
  result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Add Employee: Job-" & txtJobName.Text & "?", "Confirm Submission", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

  ' this will figure out which button was selected. Cancel and No does nothing, Yes will allow insert
  Select Case result
    Case DialogResult.Cancel
      MessageBox.Show("Action Canceled")
    Case DialogResult.No
      MessageBox.Show("Action Canceled")
    Case DialogResult.Yes

      strSelect = "SELECT MAX(intEmployeeID) + 1 AS intNextHighestRecordID " &
                    " FROM TEmployees"

      ' Execute command
      cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
      dr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

      ' Read result( highest ID )
      dr.Read()

      ' Null? (empty table)
      If dr.IsDBNull(0) = True Then

        ' Yes, start numbering at 1
        intNextHighestRecordID = 1

      Else

        ' No, get the next highest ID
        intNextHighestRecordID = CInt(dr.Item(0))

      End If
      ' add the child record
      strInsert = "Insert into TEmployees (intEmployeeID, strFirstName, strLastName)" &
        " Values (" & intNextHighestRecordID & ",'" & strFirstName & "'," & "'" & strLastName & "')"

      cmdInsert = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strInsert, m_conAdministrator)
      intRowsAffected = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
      'add the parent record
      strInsert = "Insert into TJobEmployees (intJobID, intEmployeeID)" &
                " Values (" & intJobID & ",'" & intNextHighestRecordID & "')"

      ' Insert the record(s) 
      cmdInsert = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strInsert, m_conAdministrator)
      intRowsAffected = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

      If intRowsAffected > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Job has been added")
        Me.Close()
      End If

  End Select

  CloseDatabaseConnection()

  Form1_Load(sender, e)

End If
```

Comment: Why you need `SelectedIndex` if you already has jobId from `intJobID = CInt(frmSelectJobName.lstJobs.SelectedValue)`?

Comment: I need to take the EmployeeID and JobID and put them into another table TJobEmployee.  Basically this table is saying you can have an employee working on one or many jobs.  If there is another way to add employee to jobs.  I am up to completely reworking this.

Comment: What kind of problem you have with `SelectedIndex` then?

Comment: May be you must close the form from caller form after take selectedindex data

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention the specific error.  I get a Foreign Key Constraint error on TJobEmployees_TJobs_FK in table TJobs in intJobID column

Comment: @KrisScheid that's because the .SelectedIndex of a ComboBox has nothing to do with the ID of the job code in the database.

Comment: @KrisScheid what database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: @HardCode.  I don't understand because the ID is in my SELECT statement and is also the ValueMember for loading the listbox.  I know I keep saying combobox, meant listbox

Comment: I assume you're using a version of SQL Server, based off the Management Studio comment. I recommend you create an `IDENTITY` field in your tables. That eliminates the not-so-reliable `MAX(intEmployeeID) + 1`. There are a lot of other recommendations, such as instantiating your OleDb objects with the `Using` construct. Let me see if I can put some suggestions together...

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of refactoring you should do to this code. Start with this, and it will help you get to where you want to go:

- Drop the antiquated Hungarian Notation.
- Have your job picker form expose two properties: SelectedJobName and SelectedJobID
- Give the job picker form a more meaning name, because it doesn't return only the job name. e.g. `JobPickerForm`.
- Instantiate an instance of the job picker form: `Using f As New frmSelectJobName`
- Grab the selected values from the properties: e.g. `selectedJobID = f.SelectedJobID`
- Ask the user if they want to really add the Employee **before** validation and connection checks.
- You're using SQL Server. Use objects in the SqlClient namespace instead of OleDb.
- Declare your employee ID field in the database as an `IDENTITY` field, so you don't have to use the hacky `MAX(ID) + 1`.
- Use Stored Procedures for your queries. The current method is open to SQL injection. While you could still use inline SQL, I find SPs preferable myself.
- Return the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` of the employee added to the employee table. This gives you the added employee's primary key value.
- Instantiate all of your SqlClient objects with the `Using` construct. Declare and open your SqlConnection locally to the Sub/Function, and not somewhere else.
- Whatever is in Form_Load(), put it into a separate Sub, and call that sub. You're passing a `sender`, and from your code snippet, I have no idea what event this code is in.

Do these, and if your issue persists, update your original post with your refactored code, and I'll continue helping by editing my answer.

Here is an example of a refactored JobPickerForm's properties.

```
Public Class JobPickerForm

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedJobID As Integer = 0
    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedJobName As String = String.Empty


    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        ' Whatever code you have that loads the JobsListBox.....

    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectButtonClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectButton.Click

        _SelectedJobID = CInt(JobsListBox.ValueMember)
        _SelectedJobName = JobsListBox.DisplayMember.ToString

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is an example of using the new JobPickerForm:

```
Dim selectedJobName As String = String.Empty
Dim selectedJobID As Integer = 0

Using f As New JobPickerForm

    f.ShowDialog()

    selectedJobID = f.SelectedJobID
    selectedJobName = f.SelectedJobName

End Using
```